# Show that $B((a,b),r) \subset A\times B$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> **Question:**
>   Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Prove that $A \times B$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**NOTE:**

Fellow M.SE users pointed out that the question lacks additional information/assumptions. This was pointed out to be the assumption that both $A$ and $B$ are open sets.

Let's "pretend" that it was present in the question, and then look at my proof :)

**My attempt:**

Let $(a,b) \in A \times B$ such that $a \in A, b \in B$. Now we know there exists $r_a >0, r_b>0$ such that $( a - r_a, a + r_a) \subset A$ and $(b - r_b, b + r_b) \subset B$.

Let $r = \min \{r_a, r_b \}$

Let $y \in B((a,b),r)$

$\implies || (y_1, y_2) - (a,b)|| < r$

$\implies \sqrt{(a - y_1)^2 + (b - y_2)^2} < r$

$\implies (a - y_1)^2 + (b - y_2)^2 < r^2$

Notice that this is the interior region of a circle in $A \times B$ with midpoint $y = (y_1, y_2)$ and radius $r$.

$\implies y \in A \times B$

$\implies B((a,b),r) \subset A \times B$

Is this correct? If not, can someone please point out where I went wrong and how I can go about improving the current proof? :)

**EDIT: Here is the given question exactly**
[image]

Comment: Without any further conditions on $A,B$ this cannot be proved. I reckon $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @drhab - the info in the question was the only things given. The part up until where they define $r$ was given as a hint that said we must then show that $B((a,b),r) \subset A \times B$

Comment: But you say: "we know there exists $r_a>0$ such that $(a-r_a,a+r_a)\subset A$" How do you know that?

Comment: @Dillon : Let $A=B=\mathbb{N}$. Then $A \times B = \mathbb{N}^2$. This should not be open.

Comment: @Dillon I take it you are working in the usual topologies on both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so I also don't see how that could possibly be true.

Comment: @drhab - I edited in a picture of the exact given question

Comment: The book is definitely wrong then. They just forgot to say that $A$ and $B$ are open. "WHY??" is a good expression for the despair of the reader.

Comment: @drhab Haha!! Thank you! :) :). I will point this out to the lecturer who set it up :). But, in the case that it was given $A$ and $B$ are open, is my proof then correct?

Comment: Your proof is okay except that $(a-y_1)^2-(b-y_2)^2$ must change into $(a-y_1)^2+(b-y_2)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but one or two lines are missing: From
$$(y_1-a)^2+(y_2-b)^2<r^2$$
it follows that
$$|y_1-a|<r\leq r_a\ ,$$
whence $y_1\in A$, and similarly $y_2\in B$.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is not true without additional assumption on $A$ and $B$. If for example  $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1\}$ the $A \times B $ is not open.

Since you do not assume that $A$ and $B$ are open in the statement, it is not true that there exists such  $r_a$ and $r_b$.

Comment: I edited in a photo of the exact question

Comment: As pointed out in comments above, the question is missing the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are open.

Comment: Thank you :). If those assumptions were to be given though, is my proof okay? :)

Comment: Well the proof is correct, but it is not true that $B((y_1,y_2),r)$ is in $A \times B$. Correct argumentation is:  $(a-y_1) + (b - y_2) < r^2$  implies that $y_1 \in A$ and $y_2 \in B$ and therefore $y \in A \times B$, which implies $B((a,b),r)$ is a subset of $A \times B$.